# Dotnet build fails for projects containing UserControl (InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, build, msbuild

I have a project with the .csproj defined using the .NET Core format.  The project contains user control files consisting of a .xaml file and an associated .cs file.  Previously I got a compilation error on those user controls until I added the following content to the .csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="**\*.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Compile Update="**\*.xaml.cs" SubType="Code" DependentUpon="%(Filename)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

At that point the solution began to compile within Visual Studio.  However, when I attempt to build from the command line using dotnet build, the build fails with the error I had previously seen in Visual Studio: `The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context.`

Any ideas why the solution builds in VS2017 but not using dotnet build, or how I go about fixing this?

**EDIT**: .csproj content without PackageReferences

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LanguageTargets>$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets</LanguageTargets>
    <TargetFramework>net45</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>true</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Include="**\*.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Compile Update="**\*.xaml.cs" SubType="Code" DependentUpon="%(Filename)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xaml" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: This project is completely unsuitable for .NETCore, it doesn't make sense to build with with dotnet.exe.  Use msbuild.

Comment: @HansPassant The reason I'm attempting to do so is because I'm trying to design build content that can be reused across different solutions; I'd prefer to not parse the .csproj to determine which build tool to use. When you say it's unsuitable, does that mean it's completely incompatible? Also, I thought dotnet build was running MSBuild under the hood - is that not the case?

Comment: @ket, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @Leo Liu-MSFT, sorry, I neglected to accept your answer.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Dotnet build fails for projects containing UserControl (InitializeComponent does not exist in the current context)

At this moment, I am afraid you have to use the MSBuild cli instead of using dotnet build. That because XAML files are not supported by the dotnet cli at this moment. MS team is working hard to solve this problem.

**Although**, The new sdk csproj (net461) works after compiling and deploying, but Visual Studio can't parse `.xaml` files during development as it expects .NET core views.

So, to resolve this issue, you can use the MSBuild cli instead of dotnet build.

See [XAML files are not supported](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/1467) for more details.

Comment: Since VS 16.1 this should be supported, but I still have the same problem (in VS 16.2).